# ZED SDK Crashes when used with pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation

Tags: point-cloud-library, eigen3, tegra, zed-sdk

I've installed ZED SDK version 1.0.0b on Jetson TX1 board (32bit Linux For Tegra R24.1). It turns out that it crashes most of the time for some strange reason when I use it with pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation.

I could narrow it down to the following simple program.
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
project(zed_test)

IF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
ENDIF(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

SET(CUDA_VERSION "7.0")
find_package(CUDA ${CUDA_VERSION} REQUIRED)

find_package(ZED 1.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)

include_directories(
        ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${ZED_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(${ZED_LIBRARY_DIR})
link_directories(${CUDA_LIBRARY_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(-std=c++11)# -m64) #-Wall)

add_executable(zed_test zed_test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
        zed_test
        ${ZED_LIBRARIES}
        ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_nppi_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_npps_LIBRARY}
        ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

zed_test.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <thread>

#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/features/integral_image_normal.h>

#include <zed/Camera.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "Started\n";
    //(1)
    typedef pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal> NormalEstimator;
    NormalEstimator::Ptr ne_(new NormalEstimator);

    //(2)
    sl::zed::InitParams zed_params;
    zed_params.unit = sl::zed::UNIT::METER;
    zed_params.coordinate = sl::zed::COORDINATE_SYSTEM::RIGHT_HANDED;
    zed_params.mode = sl::zed::MODE::PERFORMANCE;
    zed_params.verbose = true;
    std::unique_ptr<sl::zed::Camera> zed(new sl::zed::Camera(sl::zed::HD720, 30));
    sl::zed::ERRCODE err = sl::zed::ERRCODE::ZED_NOT_AVAILABLE;
    while (err != sl::zed::SUCCESS) {
        err = zed->init(zed_params);
        std::cout << sl::zed::errcode2str(err);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
    }

    //(3)
    std::cout << "\nPassed.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When built into Release and started, it crashes often (about once in three sequential runs) with following output:

```
Started
ZED SDK >> (Init) Best GPU Found : GM20B , ID : 0
ZED SDK >> (Init) Disparity mode has been set to PERFORMANCE
ZED SDK >> (Init) Creating ZED GPU mem...
ZED SDK >> (Init) Starting Self-Calibration in background... 
ZED SDK >> (Init) Done...
zed_test: /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h:632: const MatrixVType& Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>::matrixV() const [with _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>; int QRPreconditioner = 2; Eigen::JacobiSVD<MatrixType, QRPreconditioner>::MatrixVType = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>; typename _MatrixType::Scalar = double]: Assertion `computeV() && "This JacobiSVD decomposition didn't compute V. Did you ask for it?"' failed.
SUCCESSThe program has unexpectedly finished.
```

(note that it died before reaching the line (3))
If I comment off either creating pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation (lines under (1)) or opening the zed camera (lines under (2)) no crash occurs. If I swap them the crash is still there.

Has anyone had the problem?
Anyone from stereolabs.com to make hint of a workaround to try?

Comment: Could someone with high reputation create a tag ZED-SDK (SDK from https://www.stereolabs.com/ for ZED stereo camera)? It seems there already are quite a few ZED SDK specific questions here on SO and, arguably, there going to be plenty new questions related. Having the tag would make it easier to search and subscribe to these questions. Thank you.

Comment: Bump! Having same issue but with pcl::VoxelGrid<>. Simply having one (stack or heap) in code that isn't even called is enough to crash the program with that assertion: `computeV() && "This JacobiSVD decomposition didn't compute V. Did you ask for it?"`

Googling resources:
[HERE](https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/roscon_2015/issues/4)
[HERE](http://www.pcl-users.org/Can-t-avoid-Eigen-alignment-problems-td2531193.html)
Tried them, no luck... maybe something to do with the ARM chipset and TX1?